# Can I do a generic chainable proc with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

I have this block :

```
          return $( "<li></li>" )
              .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
              .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
              .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

And I want to put a ternary in the `append` statement so that its either just a `label` or a `label with an address`

```
item.address != '' ? item.address : ''
```

or a little messier but more specific..

```
if ( item.address != '' )
  "<span class='customer_search_addr'>" + item.address + "</span>"
else
  "<a>" + item.label + "</a>"
```

Can I make a chainable proc here since I can't ( I don't think I can ) add this ternary directly within an append statement.

Comment: It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/5LpqL/

Comment: Does it really have to be in one line? Make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a ternary into the `append` call:

```
return $( "<li></li>" )
          .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
          .append( (item.address != '')?("<span class='customer_search_addr'>" + item.address + "</span>"):("<a>" + item.label + "</a>") )
          .appendTo( ul );
```

Hovewer, it's quite messy, so i would do it like this:

```
var address = (item.address != '')?
    ("<span class='customer_search_addr'>" + item.address + "</span>"):
    ("<a>" + item.label + "</a>");

 return $( "<li></li>" )
          .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
          .append(address)
          .appendTo( ul );
```

Comment: Great answer j0hn. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It should work.. the argument will be evaluated first and so it would just passing the result to the function.

Proof demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5LpqL/

But I believe it is better if you evaluate it first like below,

```
var stuffToAppend = (item.address)?"<a>" + item.label + "</a>":"<span class='customer_search_addr'>" + item.address + "</span>";

return $( "<li></li>" )
              .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
              .append( stuffToAppend )
              .appendTo( ul );
```

Even better is to have the `if..else` condition..